# Harry Potter Dobble legend/key

Tags: untagged

I bought Dobble - Harry Potter edition to play at work, and inside there's a key to some of the symbols; but not all. Some of the guys who play don't know all the names of the items/characters, which causes some contentious issues when they match on "train" instead of Hogwarts Express or "boy with blonde hair" rather than Draco Malfoy.

Does anyone know of a single-page PDF or equivelant which has all the symbols with the character/object names next to them for reference?

P.S. I couldn't find a suitable tag.